# Un man que no le coma a nada

Tags: verbos, modismos, significado

I have heard the following line in the Narcos TV series:

> Voy a necesitar un conductor sin antecedentes que me mueva por la ciudad. Un man inteligente, que no le coma a nada, que sea un berraco.

Context: Pablo Escobar is ordering his men to find a car driver to drive him around Medellin and says the sentence above.

What does "comerse a nada" mean here? I have searched in https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=comer , https://dle.rae.es/comer and http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=comer , but I have not found the intended meaning of "comerse" in this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, *Comer* is a synonym of *Temer* (at least in the Colombian dialect), so *que no le coma a nada* is *que no le tema a nada*. Unfortunately, there is not much documentation about this term. (The best you can do is find "no le come a nadie" with the quotations marks in [google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=oBcIXpHANa_t5gLfrYXYAQ&q=%22no%20le%20come%20a%20nadie%22&oq=%22no%20le%20come%20a%20nadie%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i7i10i30.27660.27743..29090...0.0..0.164.614.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.9TOdXndGnlg&ved=0ahUKEwiRkKrU79nmAhWvtlkKHd9WARsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), and there is some examples when you can replace *comer* by *temer* and is the same.)

Comment: I wonder if this is related?  https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Comase+ésta.php